# RegEx: Getting Shopify handle from URL

Tags: regex, shopify

https://store.myshopify.com/products/burton-custom-freestyle-151

https://store.myshopify.com/products/burton-custom-freestyle-151?variant=31722273144379

From the above: I would like to output: **burton-custom-freestyle-151**

I got the following regex: [^/]*(?=\?) but only work for the 2nd link.

Comment: You could also use a capturing group `^.*/([^?\s]+)` https://regex101.com/r/UsXAnc/1 or `(?<=/)[^/?\s]+(?=\?|$)`

Comment: `(?=\?)` means *if followed by a literal question mark". You obviously don't have that in the first URL. You really need to articulate your requirements; an example which doesn't work is poor guidance for how it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
(?<=products\/)((?!\?|\$).)+
```

Comment: If there is a collection in the URL:

https://store.myshopify.com/collection/featured-products/products/burton-custom-freestyle-151?variant=31722273144379

it will come up as: 
products/burton-custom-freestyle-151
instead of 
burton-custom-freestyle-151

How can I mod the regex to get it to work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: nvm figured it out /(?<=\/products\/)((?!\?|\$).)+/

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Shopify store's template .liquid files, you can just use
`{{ page.title }}` or `{{ page.handle }}` to check for the specific product ([docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/objects/product#product-handle)).

Or `{{ page.id }}` that would not change when the user changes the title of product page.

If you're scraping web pages from a Python or Node backend, you can also use URL parsers ([urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) and [url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) respectively).